# How to use redisson stream with unblocked read?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, redisson

Recently, I want to use Redis to realize a queue scene and there are two undetermined schemes in Redis, List or Stream (since 5.0). But when I search the API, I don't find unBlock read API in the stream, but there are unBlock Api(BLPOP, BRPOP, BRPOPLPUSH) for List. And I don't want to write code like

```
while(true) {
    RStream<Object, Object> stream = redissonClient.getStream(key);
    Map<StreamMessageId, Map<Object, Object>> read = stream.read();
    Thread.sleep(10L);
}
```

So how can I achieve the target? (I used Radisson In the project.)

Can't find a suitable API in the Radisson.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
RFuture<Map<StreamMessageId, Map<Object, Object>>> readFuture = stream.readAsync();

// cancel blocking operation and release the used connection
readFuture.cancel(true);
```